# Search for synonyms in php sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am searching for string in mysql database in php,which i m doing with like keyword.The problem is when i am having synonyms entered from user.Like in the database i m having all the products with the name shoes,and user enters footwear or some mismatched words.how to search for these different conditions..
Please guide on this.

Currently i m using following select query

```
Select * from table where name like '%user entered string%'
```

Please guide on how to tackle these conditions

Comment: Only thing you can do is keep a list (or a table) of synonyms and what they should be looking for instead, no program will do this for you differently.

Comment: k.it means before searching in my actual table i shud go to my synonym table and get the list of synonym of that word and then search in my main table.is it?

Comment: Well, you could probably reference an external app - thesaurus.com, or somesuch - but it might be too broad to be useful, so I suspect Jonast92 is right.

Comment: request to u both to please check my approach in comment if its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's sum it up.

Let's assume that you have a table `products` which, I highly assume and hope, consists of products with unique ids.

```
products

id     product
1      Shoes
2      Trousers
```

And so on. If you were to add an another column, let's say, synonyms, it would look something like this:

```
products

id     product    synonyms
1      Shoes      Footwear, stuff on feet, 
2      Trousers
```

**We don't want this**. You'd have to select the synonyms column, parse the string and make sure you don't ruin the column when you somehow wish to add new synonyms to each product.

It makes much more sense to have an atomic database where you'd have a table of synonyms where each synonym references a unique id in your products table, this way it's easy to delete old synonyms and add new ones.

```
products

id     product
1      Shoes
2      Trousers

synonyms
id     product_id     synonym
1      1              Footwear
2      1              stuff on feet
```

You can then look up in this table if the original select like statement fails.

Using an external data-source is also a possibility but this is probably the most suitable way to go if you want to control the flow and avoid external sources.

Comment: @user3575612 how did it go?

Comment: @Jonast92-I tried with one synonym table and put some data in that,when user enters some data,tried reading it from tht table frst and moving forward thru code.

Comment: @user3575612 So it went well?

Comment: @user3575612 Alright but if the issue is not that the answer is wrong then I'd be good if you could accept the answer. If there arise any other problems that are not a part of the design itself but instead an implementation problem then we can continue with that discussion there, besides, this question is getting rather old.

Comment: Can we possibly find a mysql db compiled of synonyms of each English word. Than would be GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way is , add all match possibility  keywords (shoes, footwear, men dress and etc.) to all products (to keywords column) when you add to base , which user will be search. And search products from this column(or table).

Comment: according to ur approach,i shud add keywords like shoes,footwear etc. to product list table only.no need of making any synonym table!!!

Comment: Your database should be as atomic as possible, it's going to be a pain in the ass to select a string from your product table and attach a new string when you want to and then later you have to parse the string of synonym, it makes much more sense to have an atomic table where each row consist of a single synonym and an id to your product table.

Comment: means separate table for product and synonyms ,ryt?

Comment: @Jonast92 this way is atomic than to go to the synonym table and get the list of synonym of that word and then search in main table. isnt it?